# Group Isomorphism Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is A is isomorphic to B and B is not Isomorphic to C, why does this imply A is not isomorphic to C?
I understand that if the size of D is not equal to the size of E, this implies D is not isomorphic to E, but unfortunately the implication is the wrong way round for this proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Being isomorphic to* is a symmetric transitive relation.

If $A$ were isomorphic to $C$, then $B$ would be isomorphic to $C$ via $A$, as in $B \cong A \cong C$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Prove that

$$\begin{cases}\phi:G\to B\;\;\text{isomorphism}\\
\xi:G\to C\;\;\text{isomorphism}\end{cases}\;\;\implies\;\xi\circ\phi^{-1}:B\to C\;\;\text{isomorphism}$$